# New IIS7 virtual directory does not show on FTP client. What needs to happen?

Tags: iis-7, ftp, virtual-directory

First, I might have to do this *maybe* once a year, so my memory is failing me as what exactly I did before to get this work because I've been able to do this times prior.  We are using an ISS 7 ftp server to recieve internal file transfers from an AIX server we have in house.  The only difference between then and now is that the existing virtual directories were migrated from a Windows 2003 (IIS 6) server to a Windows 2008 server.

All permisions from the existing directories are exactly the same as the new directory, yet the new virtual directory will not show in the any of the FTP clients I'm testing.  I do have FTP Directory Browsing turned on for the Default Site which is where all Virtual Directories reside.  The only thing I haven't done is stop/start IIS (which I don't remeber doing in the past), but I didn't want to needlessly restart IIS on a production server to only end up in the same place I am now.  What do I need to do to get this working?

**UPDATE**

Ok, had some down time to give IIS a restart, but no avail.  I am still not able to browse or view my newly created virtual directory on any FTP client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  We have a login script for all machines that maps a network drive.  It just so happens that the server I was working is the source of the mapped drive, the share on the server gets mapped as a drive.  Instead of using the actual path to directory I was trying to use for the virtural directory, I discovered I accidentally chose the mapped drive instead.  Once I reset virtual directory to the physical location on the drive, the directory appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the folder were migrated from IIS/2003. I suggest that you verify the permissions the directories to make sure that the App Pool Identity that your FTP site is running on have permission to them. What authentication method are you using? Does IIS log indicate whether connections from the client are established successfully?